# How to make your own table migration of two different tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, merge

I was wondering how I can make a table migration of two different tables.

**Let me simply explain the question**

So let us say we have database `a` and a database `b`.
In both databases we have a table called `user`.
The table of `user@a` is the develop table and the table `user@b` is the production table.

Good. Now we have in `user@a` the following columns: `username`, `password`and `email`.

In `user@b` we have the following columns: `username`, `password`, `email` and `role`.
Now I need to merge these two tables.

So it needs to make a new column (same as `user@b`) and store the data in the column.

I have no idea of how I can do this.
If someone can help me with giving me a start I would be pleased.

I don't know if you should be able writing some websoftware to simply merge 2 databases. Since I'm a webdeveloper I may want to do that. So if someone can start me up with some more information... thanks!

Comment: is there a reason why you can't do a one off [ALTER TABLE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp) to update the development table? generally the development environment should be matching the production environment. also are you expecting new non-test data from development to be going on production?

Comment: You didn't understand it well... It is the production environment that will be updated with (tested) software and new stuff. So the production environment gets the merge.